# All values of AUC ROC Curve 1 using tidymodels

Tags: r, lasso-regression, tidymodels

Trying to do a LASSO model with a binary outcome using tidymodels, I have essentially copied the case study from the tidymodels webpage (https://www.tidymodels.org/start/case-study/)(the hotel stay dataset) and applied it to my own data but for some reason all of the values on my area under the ROC curve are coming out at 1 (as you can see from graph below). The only thing I have changed is the recipe (to try and suit my data)

```
  recipe(outcome ~ ., data = df_train) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>% 
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_medianimpute(all_predictors())
```

so I don't know if it is my recipe that is incorrect or my data is not suitable for whatever reason. As mentioned I have a binary outcome and 68 predictors (59 factors and 9 numeric), some do have missing data but thought that the step_medianimpute would deal with that. Many thanks for any help anyone can offer

[My AUC ROC Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CMHv.png)

Comment: how many predictors are left at the highest penalty? Its hard to find the reasons without having the actual data used.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data it is hard to know for sure, but your results indicate a couple of things.

Firstly, AUC ROC of 1. An AOC ROC of 1 for a binary classification model indicated that the model is perfectly able to separate the two classes. This could either be the case of overfitting or that you just have linearly separable classes.

Secondly, the constant metric value for different values of penalty. For a LASSO model, as the penalty increases, more and more variables will be shrunk to zero. In your case for all the values of the penalty (if you are following the post it will be `10^(-4)` through `10^(-1)`) you are seeing the same performance. That means that even if you use a penalty of `10^(-1)` you still haven't shrunk enough predictors to hurt/change the performance. Reprex below

```r
set.seed(1234)
library(tidymodels)
response <- rep(c(0, 10), length.out = 1000)

data <- bind_cols(
  response = factor(response),
  map_dfc(seq_len(50), ~ rnorm(1000, response)) 
)

data_split <- initial_split(data)

data_train <- training(data_split)
data_test <- testing(data_split)

lasso_spec <- logistic_reg(mixture = 1, penalty = tune()) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet")

lasso_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(lasso_spec) %>%
  add_formula(response ~ .)

data_folds <- vfold_cv(data_train)

param_grid <- tibble(penalty = 10^seq(-4, -1, length.out = 30))

tune_res <- tune_grid(
  lasso_wf, 
  resamples = data_folds, 
  grid = param_grid
)

autoplot(tune_res)
```

[image]

What what you can do is expand the range of penalties until you the performance changes. Below we see that once the penalty is high enough, the last important predictors got shrunk to zero, and we lose performance.

```r
param_grid <- tibble(penalty = 10^seq(-1, 0, length.out = 30))

tune_res <- tune_grid(
  lasso_wf, 
  resamples = data_folds, 
  grid = param_grid
)

autoplot(tune_res)
```

[image]

To verify, we fit the model using one of the good performance penalties and we get perfect predictions.

```r
lasso_final <- finalize_workflow(lasso_wf, select_best(tune_res))

lasso_final_fit <- fit(lasso_final, data = data_train)

augment(lasso_final_fit, new_data = data_train) %>%
  conf_mat(truth = response, estimate = .pred_class)
#>           Truth
#> Prediction   0  10
#>         0  375   0
#>         10   0 375
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your help! unfortunately it is all medical data so impossible to share for confidentiality reasons. I have edited my data accordingly and expanded the grid and I do get a drop off in accuracy and ROC-AUC very similar to your graphs above, still getting suspiciously good readings which can't be true so there must be something wrong with my underlying data or what I'm including in the model. Thanks again!

Comment: You might have a data leakage problem. I think you are correct in trying to figure out if you are including a predictor you shouldn't have.

Comment: Is there any way of definitively checking for data leakage? Or is always a "suspected" data leakage?